# Sql Server Protect Instance

Tags: sql-server

Is there anyway to protect access to SQL server installation ?

I mean I want that only a single user will be able to access the database and no one else    , not even by Windows Authentication.
I want to do this because I dont want anyone to look into the database and see the details of the database.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? (In 2008 & R2 local admins are not in the `sysadmin` role by default this should be easier.)

Comment: It's sql server 2008 express.

Comment: I have sql server 2008 express installed and I can log in using windows authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was install it normally and delete all logins in security except the user sa.

Comment: This is good, but I would add one more login in addtion to sa, and not use the sa account for anything.